# Оборот с союзом "чем"

Tags: синтаксис

> Нет ничего страшнее, чем потеря близких.

"Чем потеря близких" - какой член предложения?

Answer (score 2):

§ 2096. Союз **чем (и нежели)** служит для выражения градационного сравнения, т. е. сравнения по соотношению измеряемого: ***груша слаще, чем яблоко***; ***белее, чем снег; более холодный, чем всегда***.
**При компаративе** словоформа с союзом чем (и нежели) занимает позицию **восполняющей формы**: На темном небе начали мелькать звезды, и странно, мне показалось, что они гораздо выше, чем у нас на севере (Лерм.); Здесь было светлее, чем в поле (Чех.); Она была, смущена еще более, чем я (Катаев); Осина больше сочетается с северным сероватым небом, нежели с пылающей лазурью небес (Солоух.).(http://rusgr [am.narod.ru/2090-2099.html)](http://am.narod.ru/2090-2099.html))

**Вопрос** к сравнительным конструкциям задать трудно. В справочниках эту тему авторы как-то удачно обходят. Как? В сравнении с чем? Принято считать сравнительные обороты **обстоятельствами**, хотя иногда они похожи на дополнения. Неслучайно в приведённой цитате говорится, что при компаративе они занимают позицию "восполняющей формы".  Хотелось бы на этот счёт услышать мнение коллег.

Comment: Спасибо! Если провести аналогию с синонимичным предложением "Нет ничего страшнее потери близких", становится понятно, почему речь идет о дополнении. Действительно, вопрос к градационному сравнительному обороту задать сложно, и вариант : "Нет ничего страшнее (чего?)-
чем потеря близких" -  нисколько не хуже других)))

Answer (score 0):

"Чем потеря близких" - это сравнительный оборот, а сравнительный оборот - это обстоятельство. В данном предложении - обстоятельство степени

Comment: Спасибо! А какой вопрос здесь уместен? "Чем что"?

Comment: нет страшнее (как? в какой степени?) чем потеря близких